# Download images in python

Tags: python, streamlit

i have a app which convert the image to pencil sketch here i am trying to download the output image in browser previously i have done but its downloading inside the browser

Is there any other way to download the image in browser

```
import streamlit as st
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw
import cv2
    


      if st.button("Download Sketch Images"):
        im_pil = Image.fromarray(final_sketch)
        im_pil.save('Pencil Sketch.jpeg')
        st.write('Download completed')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a widget included in streamlit to do what you ask for.

```
st.download_button(label="Download Sketch Images", data=im_pil.tobytes(), file_name='Pencil Sketch.jpeg')
```

https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.download_button

Comment: I am getting this error ("Invalid binary data format: %s" % type(data))

Comment: i forgot to convert the Image object to bytes. I updated my answer

Comment: got another error  __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: to_bytes

Comment: I'm so sorry, the method is called tobytes instead of to_bytes

Comment: nice! can you please mark my answer as helpful (assuming it was)?